# How to understand this pointer to a data structure in C?

Tags: c

I have this code, I'm trying to figure out what the second line of code does.

```
static int table [][4]= {{1,2,3,4},{2,3,4,5},{3,4,5,6}};
int valore = *(*(table+2)+1);
printf("%d",valore);
```

I have a basic knowledge of pointers in C, can you explain me what does the second line of code do please?

Comment: `*(*(table+2)+1);` is `*(table[2]+1);` is `table[2][1]` There is no difference. `*(a + b)` is pointer notation for `a[b]` (which is also the same as `b[a]`) in index notation. (`table` is simple a 2D array of `int`, thus `*(*(table+2)+1)` (or `table[2][1]`) just references the 2nd element of the 3rd row, so you print `4`)

Comment: post it as a solution please, so i can vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table` is an array of 3 arrays of 4 `int`.

When an array is used in an expression, it is converted to a pointer to its first element, except when:

- It is the operand of `sizeof`.
- It is the operand of unary `&`.
- It is a string literal used to initialize an array.

So, in `*(*(table+2)+1)`, `table` is converted to a pointer to its first element, producing `&table[0]`. Then we have:

```
*(*(&table[0]+2)+1)
```

Next, we have the addition `&table[0] + 2`. This uses pointer arithmetic. Adding an integer to a pointer (into an array) moves the pointer backward or forward by a number of elements. So `&table[0] + 2` produces a pointer to `table[2]`, which is `&table[2]`. Then we have:

```
*(*(&table[2])+1)
```

The inner parentheses are no longer needed, so we have:

```
*(*&table[2]+1)
```

Then `* &table[2]` is the thing that `&table[2]` points to, which means it is `table[2]`:

```
*(table[2] + 1)
```

Since `table` is an array of 3 arrays of 4 `int`, `table[2]` is an array of 4 `int`. Since it is an array, it is converted to a pointer to its first element, producing `&table[2][0]`:

```
*(&table[2][0] + 1)
```

Now we have pointer arithmetic again. `&table[2][0]` is a pointer to element 0 of the array `table[2]`, so adding 1 produces a pointer to element 1, `&table[2][1]`:

```
*(&table[2][1])
```

Again we have parentheses that are no longer needed:

```
*&table[2][1]
```

And, finally, `* &table[2][1]` is the thing that `&table[2][1]` points to, so it is just:

```
table[2][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `table` is simply a 2D array of integers. In C a 2D array is really an "*array or arrays*". Your `table` has the dimensions of `static in table[3][4];` (3 rows x 4 cols), it is an array of 3 integer arrays with 4 elements each. Since it is an array, all values will be sequential in memory. You can think of the memory layout as follows.

```
            +---+---+---+---+
table[0]    | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
            +---+---+---+---+
table[1]    | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
            +---+---+---+---+
table[2]    | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
            +---+---+---+---+
```

An array is converted to a pointer on access (accept in 4 limited circumstances, not relevant here, see [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) for details)

You are introduced to "*pointer notation*" in the question. You can access any element of an array using "*array indexes*" or "*pointer notation*". In pointer notation `*(a + b)` is equivalent to `a[b]` in array index notation. You have:

```
*(*(table+2)+1)
```

If you take it piece by piece `*(table + 2)` is simply `table[2]`. Next `*(table[2] + 1)` is simply `table[2][1]`. So you are acccessing the 2nd value in the 3rd row with either (which is simply `4`).

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.